# How can I split a string into meaningful tokens?

Tags: java, string, parsing

I need a better way of splitting the following string. I am not sure how to identify a substring and assign it to the correct variable:

> at Manchester (Old Trafford)  24/8/1972    England won by 6 wickets  [35 balls remaining]

I wanted to split the above string and assign substrings to different variables.

```
Venue --> Manchester (Old Trafford)
Date --> 24/8/1972
Result --> England won by 6 wickets  [35 balls remaining]
```

I tried `StringTokenizer`, but I felt it was too much work to get the assignment as above, and moreover it is too complex. When I used `StringTokenizer` I got the following substrings:

> at
>   Manchester
>   (Old
>   Trafford)
>   24/8/1972
>   England
>   won
>   by
>   6
>   wickets
>   [35
>   balls
>   remaining]

Please suggest any better ways of doing it.

Comment: Perhaps you should explore a bit into Regular Expressions.

Comment: One example input does not a specification make.  Either say in plain English what the specification is (what pattern will the input follow?) or give more examples so that we can learn by example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all of the strings have the same format (venue, slash-separated date, result), you could use a regular expression.

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(.+) (\\d+/\\d+/\\d+) (.+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(record);
if (!m.matches()) 
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid record format.");
String venue = m.group(1);
String date = m.group(2);
String result = m.group(3);
...
```

This assumes that the venue will never contain a substring that looks like a date.

Comment: You showed me the way in Regex, thank you and solution is short.